# Get paid through Payoneer or through crypto? what advice can you give?

Tags: salary, salaried-pay

Get paid through Payoneer or through crypto? what advice can you give?

Comment: I recommend getting paid with real money

Comment: I just want to escape the tax field

Comment: I do not recommend trying to avoid tax

Comment: @user138040 there are only 2 things certain in life... Death & Taxes... ask Al Capone.

Comment: @Kupo I do various things to [_avoid_ tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_avoidance) - for instance, paying money into my pension. I do not [evade tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_evasion), however.

Comment: _"I just want to escape the tax field"_ Expect any legitimate employer to refrain from such practices due to legal, tax and payroll implications. If you consider to work for shady-corp ask them how they usually launder their hard currency.. Also be awayre that tax-evasion is considered a criminal act in most countries.

Comment: If you get paid for work in any form, that is taxable income. Period. There are methods of payment that make it harder (but not impossible) for the tax bureau to find out about, but that's called tax evasion and is illegal. Trying to evade taxes can get both you and your employer in a lot of trouble.

Comment: In large parts of the world, the currency for salaries is fixed. Otherwise, how would you ever have laws about minimum wage? Is two chickens and a goat for two months of 40h weeks above or below 15$ minimum wage? It does not work this way. So please at least specify your country.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your employer.

Be prepared to explain this to your manager in a way that doesn’t involve the payroll department being party to any illegal tax evasion.

Since you used the “salary” tag, I assume that someone will be employing you and you’re not offering services as an individual.

Answer (score -1):

There are costs and risks no matter how you get paid. When paid with government issued money, the costs are taxes. The risks are low and include inflation. (Although, I have had a check take 3 weeks to travel a few miles.)

When getting paid with crypto, you have the costs of currency translation and the value risks. The value of the crypto could drop between the time the other party pays and the time you try to convert the crypto. These costs and risks could be as high as the tax burden (or higher depending on the market). You also have the risks of the crypto exchange going under while holding your payment and not getting paid at all.

Many merchants that accept crypto currencies are paying for their clearing house to convert the crypto as fast as possible. That way, they minimize their exposure to currency fluctuations. For them, accepting crypto currencies is simply a customer service issue, not a good financial move.

Also, being paid through crypto is not anonymous. If you are paid from a US company, that company still has to report such payments to the IRS and you still owe taxes on those payments. Blockchain based cryptocurrencies can have the blockchain analyzed to find out how much you have been paid.

Crypto currencies make sense only when the government issued currency is not to be trusted.